# Why MILP solver for obstacle avoidance is still passing through the obstacle?

Tags: optimization, constraints, mixed-integer-programming

I have to extend the build_solver function to accept a list of obstacles: build_solver(umax, x0, T, num_steps, obstacles=[]). This requires that I need to add additional constraints to ensure that the robot does not enter the obstacle (for all times). And i have to do this by adding an additional "slack variable". Also, I have to make sure that avoiding an obstacle needs to happen at every time step; I need to add constraints for every x in xs. When the list of obstacles is empty, no constraints should be added.

So, I made the below build_solver function (remaining functions shouldnot be changed), but why it is still passing through the obstacle ?

```
# Starter Code: 2D Trajectory Optimization
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from ortools.linear_solver import pywraplp


def vec_add(vec_a, vec_b):
    return [ai + bi for ai, bi in zip(vec_a, vec_b)]


def dot(vec_a, vec_b):
    return sum([av * bv for av, bv in zip(vec_a, vec_b)])


def matmul(mat, vec):
    return [dot(mat_r, vec) for mat_r in mat]


def get_propagation_matrices(dt):
    # Define the matrices (matrices from class)
    Ad = np.array([[1, 0, dt, 0],
         [0, 1, 0, dt],
         [0, 0, 1, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 1]])
    dt2 = dt*dt/2
    Bd = np.array([

        [dt2, 0, -dt2, 0],
        [0, dt2, 0, -dt2],
        [dt, 0, -dt, 0],
        [0, dt, 0, -dt]])
    return Ad, Bd



    
def build_solver(umax, x0, T, num_steps, obstacles=[]):
    solver = pywraplp.Solver.CreateSolver('SCIP')
    infinity = solver.infinity()
    dt = T / num_steps
    Ad, Bd = get_propagation_matrices(dt)
    
    # Define the control variables
    us = [[solver.NumVar(0, umax, f'u_{step}_{side}')
            for side in range(4)] for step in range(num_steps)]
    
    # Define the slack variables for obstacle avoidance
    slack_vars = [[solver.NumVar(0, infinity, f'slack_{step}_{obs}') 
                   for obs in range(len(obstacles))]
                  for step in range(num_steps)]
    
    # Compute each state from the initial state and the thrust values
    x = x0
    xs = [x]
    for step in range(num_steps):
        x_next = vec_add(matmul(Ad, x), matmul(Bd, us[step]))
        xs.append(x_next)
        
        # Constraints for obstacle avoidance
        for obs_idx, obstacle in enumerate(obstacles):
            x_obs = obstacle[0]  # x-coordinate of the obstacle
            y_obs = obstacle[1]  # y-coordinate of the obstacle
            width_obs = obstacle[2]  # width of the obstacle
            height_obs = obstacle[3]  # height of the obstacle
            
            # Ensure the robot stays outside the obstacle region using slack variables
            for dim in range(2):  # Loop through x and y dimensions
                solver.Add(xs[step][dim] + slack_vars[step][obs_idx] >= x_obs + width_obs)
                solver.Add(xs[step][dim] - slack_vars[step][obs_idx] <= x_obs)
                solver.Add(xs[step][dim + 2] + slack_vars[step][obs_idx] >= y_obs + height_obs)
                solver.Add(xs[step][dim + 2] - slack_vars[step][obs_idx] <= y_obs)
    
        x = x_next
    
    # Add the targets for the final state and thrust
    for dim in range(4):
        solver.Add(xs[-1][dim] == 0)
    
    # Constraints on the amount of thrust and non-negativity
    for step in range(num_steps):
        for side in range(4):
            solver.Add(us[step][side] <= umax)
            solver.Add(us[step][side] >= 0)  # Ensure non-negativity
    
    solver.Minimize(dt * sum([sum(u) for u in us]))
    
    return solver, us


def replace_and_plot(x0, us, solver, T, num_steps, obstacles=[]):
    """Substitute solved values and plot."""
    x = np.array(x0)
    dt = T / num_steps
    Ad, Bd = get_propagation_matrices(dt)
    xsv = [x]
    usv =  [[us[step][side].solution_value() for side in range(4)] for step in range(num_steps)]
    for uv in usv:
        x = vec_add(matmul(Ad, x), matmul(Bd, uv))
        xsv.append(x)

    objective_value = solver.Objective().Value()
    print(f'Objective value = {objective_value}')

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    xsv = np.array(xsv)
    ax.plot(xsv[:, 0], xsv[:, 1], 'k', alpha=0.1)
    ax.scatter(xsv[:, 0], xsv[:, 1], c=list(range(num_steps+1)), s=1)
    ax.set_aspect('equal', 'box')
    
    for ob in obstacles:
        ax.add_patch(patches.Rectangle(
            (ob[0], ob[2]), ob[1] - ob[0], ob[3] - ob[2],
            linewidth=1, edgecolor='k', facecolor='none'))

    return objective_value

# Trajectory Solving (with obstacles): Results and Plotting

num_steps = 50
T = 25
umax = 0.4
x0_withV = [2, 3, 1, -2]
x0_noV = [2, 3, 0, 0]

# obstacle = [xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax]
obstacles = [[1, 2, -2.5, 2.5]]

solver, us = build_solver(umax, x0_withV, T, num_steps, obstacles)
status = solver.Solve()
replace_and_plot(x0_withV, us, solver, T, num_steps, obstacles)
plt.title("V not 0")

solver, us = build_solver(umax, x0_noV, T, num_steps, obstacles)
status = solver.Solve()
replace_and_plot(x0_noV, us, solver, T, num_steps, obstacles)
plt.title("V = 0")

solver, us = build_solver(umax, x0_withV, T, num_steps, obstacles=[])
status = solver.Solve()
replace_and_plot(x0_withV, us, solver, T, num_steps, obstacles=[])
plt.title("V not 0")

solver, us = build_solver(umax, x0_noV, T, num_steps, obstacles=[])
status = solver.Solve()
replace_and_plot(x0_noV, us, solver, T, num_steps, obstacles=[])
plt.title("V = 0")

None
```

o[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jO1ZU.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Od4q1.png)

Comment: You missed to post the code which calls `build_solver` and `replace_and_plot`.

Comment: Added the required code parts

Answer (score 0):

> Why … is still passing through the obstacle?

This question is rather easy to answer. You have constraints supposed to

```
            # Ensure the robot stays outside the obstacle region using slack variables
            for dim in range(2):  # Loop through x and y dimensions
                solver.Add(xs[step][dim] + slack_vars[step][obs_idx] >= x_obs + width_obs)
                solver.Add(xs[step][dim] - slack_vars[step][obs_idx] <= x_obs)
                solver.Add(xs[step][dim + 2] + slack_vars[step][obs_idx] >= y_obs + height_obs)
                solver.Add(xs[step][dim + 2] - slack_vars[step][obs_idx] <= y_obs)
```

- but they aren't correct.

- *xs<sub>dim</sub> + slack_vars ≥ x_obs + width_obs*, *xs<sub>dim</sub> - slack_vars ≤ x_obs* - These conditions can easily be met by a sufficiently large *slack_vars*, so they are not much of a constraint, and do not ensure staying outside the obstacle *x* region for *dim = 0*; moreover for *dim = 1*, which is the *y* coordinate, they wrongly refer to *x_obs* and *width_obs*.
- *xs<sub>dim+2</sub> + slack_vars ≥ y_obs + height_obs*, *xs<sub>dim+2</sub> - slack_vars ≤ y_obs* - These conditions do not ensure staying outside the obstacle *y* region like above; moreover *xs<sub>dim+2</sub>* are not even coordinates, so comparing them to *y_obs* plus *height_obs* seems meaningless.